# How to overlap two div with css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a page where I have two sidebars both in opposite direction. I'm using a metronic admin theme purchased from evanto, I want it to be fixed even page is being scrolled and the page content to be below that sidebar. I've placed these two menu inside a div with class `page-container` in which I'm having another div for the page content named `page-content-wrapper`.

here is the link to [my problem](http://noeticitservices.com/nitsdemo/NitsEditor/newedit/editor.php)

I tried using the following css in editor.css:

```
body {
    color: #333333;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    font-size: 13px;
    direction: ltr;
}

body {
    background: #e9ecf3;
}

.page-header-fixed {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.page-container {
    margin-top: 75px;
    padding: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.page-content-wrapper {
    z-index: 3;
}
```

I tried using `absolute position` but it becomes more messy as both the sidebars collapse. I tried putting `z-index` too but its not helping.

Content is also coming down the sidebar.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to fix the position of the element with respect to the window even when scrolling then use `position: fixed;` on that specific element.

Comment: I've already given you the link. You can inspect element in browser.

Comment: Add this right click on the sidebar find this div tag in the DOM and add the style on this element `<div class="page-sidebar navbar-collapse collapse" style="
    position: fixed;">`

Comment: Problem is when I put style fixed to the second sidebar it changes the position from right to left.